# CSS to shrink the giant SE site headers?

Tags: support, design

Several of the new StackExchange sites have rather *large* site headers, and some people have asked if it could be changed, to improve usability on small devices. Although I'm not a CSS guru, it *seems* to me that this could easily be fixed with a custom user stylesheet given to the browser, and I've been playing around with it. So far, with no success. :)

To explain precisely what I'd like to do in CSS, I'd like to:

- Shrink (or remove) the giant logo (for instance, on this page, the planet/electrons and the word "Pro Webmasters"
- Move up the buttons ("questions/tags/users, etc") to the top edge.
- Preserve the navigation link to main site, that is in center of banner.

**Before**:
[image]

**After**:
[image]

Note that I also moved the "ask questions" button left, so it would be visible without scrolling. That I managed to figure out, but unfortunately not the rest. I *think* it would involve these elements:

```
#header {
    <!-- what goes here? -->
}
#header #hmenus {
    <!-- what goes here? -->
}
.nav { float: left !important; }
```

Comment: You might want to consider the fact you're killing off the only navigation to the front page, so you should warn people that you give this to. As a separate warning, [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) and [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/) will give you separate troubles on the Ask Question button, while [Photography](http://photo.stackexchange.com/) has its own bundle of differences of layout.

Comment: @Grace Note, good point on the navigation. I *had* thought of mentioning it on the site it was for (gamedev), but *here* is probably better. And yeah, the button on Gaming doesn't work, but most of the sites I go to, do, so close enough. :)

Comment: Obvious, absurdly stupid question: How would you get back to the homepage? Also, this won't work for *all* sites, simply because of the many different types of navigation Jin has put in - as @Grace notes

Comment: @Yi Jiang - question updated. Also, I notice that my question on meta.gamedev was answered, and tracing the post back, from your CSS in a chat - why not post your answer *here*, and I'll checkmark it?